# Compile error when trying to install gst-plugins-bad 1.4.3

Tags: gstreamer, banshee

I am trying to install gst-plugins-bad 1.4.3 in order to install gstreamer-sharp 1.39 in order to install banshee 2.9.1. I downloaded the source distribution from git and was able to run `autogen.sh`, but running `make install` crashes with the following error.

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/gst'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/gst'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/gst'
Making install in sys
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/sys'
Making install in decklink
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/sys/decklink'
  CXXLD    libgstdecklink.la
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklink.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.libs/libgstdecklink_la-gstdecklink.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libgstdecklink.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/sys/decklink'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/Downloads/gst-plugins-bad/sys'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I don't know how to respond to this error and I can't seem to find anyone else who has encountered it. What should I do? I am running Linux Mint 13.

Comment: I am having the same error